# Почему при нажатии на кнопку prev - не отображается скрытый текст для слайдера

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть слайдер

http://jsfiddle.net/rkzc7mrv/

```js
jQuery("#slider-reviews").owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    navigation: true,
    pagination: false,
    itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 3],
    itemsTablet: [768, 3],
    itemsMobile: [479, 3],
    autoHeight: true,
    addClassActive: true,

    afterAction: function (el) {
        this.$owlItems.removeClass('active')

        this.$owlItems.eq(this.currentItem + 1)
            .addClass('active')
    }

});
```

```css
/*-------------------------------------------------*/

/* =  Core Owl Carousel CSS File v1.3.3. begin
/*-------------------------------------------------*/

/* clearfix */
 .owl-carousel .owl-wrapper:after {
    content:".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
/* display none until init */
 .owl-carousel {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer.autoHeight {
    -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    float: left;
}
.owl-controls .owl-page, .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.owl-controls {
    position: relative;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
.owl-controls .owl-buttons {
}
.owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    width: 59px;
    height: 58px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
.owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #f00 url('../img/slider/arrows.png') no-repeat -10px -11px;
}
.owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: #f00 url('../img/slider/arrows.png') no-repeat -90px -11px;
}
.owl-controls.clickable .owl-buttons div:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.owl-controls {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
/* mouse grab icon */
 .grabbing {
    cursor:url(grabbing.png) 8 8, move;
}
/* fix */
 .owl-carousel .owl-wrapper, .owl-carousel .owl-item {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.section-reviews {
    padding-top: 65px;
}
.section-reviews h2 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #18171A;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#slider-reviews {
    text-align: center;
}
#slider-reviews .item {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
#slider-reviews .item img {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;    
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 55px;
}
#slider-reviews .slider-text {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
#slider-reviews .item h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#slider-reviews .item p {
    font-size: 14px;
}
#slider-reviews .slider-text .list-bullet {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#slider-reviews .slider-text .list-bullet > li {
    font-size: 14px;
}
#slider-reviews .owl-item.active > div {
}
#slider-reviews .owl-item.active img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#slider-reviews .owl-item.active .slider-text {
    display: block;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------*/

/* =  Core Owl Carousel CSS File v1.3.3. end
/*-------------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div id="slider-reviews">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
        <div class="slider-text">
            <h4>Title h4</h4>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
       <div class="slider-text">
            <h4>Title h4</h4>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>     
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/owl4.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
         <div class="slider-text">
            <h4>Title h4</h4>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/owl5.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
        <div class="slider-text">
            <h4>Title h4</h4>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>     
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/owl6.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
         <div class="slider-text">
            <h4>Title h4</h4>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/owl7.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
          <div class="slider-text">
            <h4>Title h4</h4>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/owl8.jpg" alt="Owl Image">
        <div class="slider-text">
            <h4>Title h4</h4>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При загрузке самого слайдера и при нажатии на кнопку prev не отображается скрытый текст для активного блока слайдера.

Для кнопки next все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убрать из параметров `autoHeight: true`